# How do I align an SVG grid based in a DOM centered div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I got a grid made out of SVG like this:

```
<svg id="canvas-svg" class="remove-on-save" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="smallGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="#EF1D1D" stroke-width="0.7"></path>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#smallGrid)"></rect>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Thing is that is centered with the 0,0 of the entire document, I would like to align the 10x10 squares to another DIV I got centered in the screen, tried setting an offset to the grid but that didn't do the trick.

Btw, i got the SVG Grid in a wrapper div, and I wouldn't like to use left, right, top css. The grid would entirely move, i just want to align it without losing the 100% x 100% propagation of the grid.

Any idea? Thanks

I got the example on this JSFiddle i made http://jsfiddle.net/7pLhj/

See that the grid in this example doesn't match with the div that is centered? I would like to make it match, but without losing the 100% width and 100% height.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: sure i will try to set up a jsfiddle

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the solution you implemented? I still don't understand how the issue was solved or your question in general. I understand it as you want to align the centered div to the grid in the background

Comment: yea, i've used the transform="translate(X,Y)" depending on the centered div Math.round(offset().top) and Math.round(offset().left) whenever i do a $(window).resize() i just do that, and it works really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "tried setting an offset to the grid but that didn't do the trick"

I am going to guess that the way you set the offset was by setting the `x` & `y` attributes of the rect.  Is that correct?

Try doing it with a transform instead.

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)"
      transform="translate(400,500)" />
```

Where 400,500 is the offset of your div.

Comment: let me check :o i made the JSFiddle in the original post tho so you can see what I'm saying, gonna test that :)

Comment: Mmm yea, it works but it moves the entire grid and i got blank lines on the sides due to the transform. It's like setting "left: 3px", the entire Grid is being moved. Is there a chance to avoid making it "move" but only move the inner "drawing", like to match up?

Comment: How about `<rect x="-100%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="200%" fill="url(#grid)" transform="...">`

Comment: Or, assuming the pattern is not used by anything else, you can apply the transform to the pattern instead, using `patternTransform="..."`

Comment: the 200%, 200% is the one i needed, nice catch man :) haven't thought about doing that. Clever! :)